# Puzzle with the point inside paralelogram and area

Tags: mathematics, geometry

We have a paralelogram $ABCD$ and point $P$ inside it. Halflines $BP$ and $DP$ cuts respectively lines $AD$ and $AB$ at $E$ and $F$. Why are the area of $ABPD$ and $CEPF$  the same regardles of the position of $P$?

[image]

This is again some contest problem (I think), I had it in my notes for a long time (at least 10 years) and I thought it would be interesting for this site. I solved it only recently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: ![enter image description here]

> The triangles ABD, CBD, CDF and CBE all have the same area.
>  Subtracting CYD we get CYF = DYB. Subtracting BCX we get CXE = BXD.
>  The mauve quadrilateral ECFB therefore has the same area as CBD + PBD which is the same as DBA + PBD which is the same as the green quadrilateral's.

Comment: Could you please crop the picture to remove all the unnecessary whitespace?